# Why does my every-minute crontab not work but same process on @reboot works fine?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've been following carefully and reading a lot about setting up crontab with crontab -e any help is appreciated on this ...

I have a process that runs on startup (reboot) that works perfectly, and I want it to continue to run every minute but that does not happen. I do have a new-line (linefeed) at the end of the 2nd line. THANKS!!
I have program /dir/xxx that works great on reboot but the same process set to run every minute never triggers. My crontab -e is as follows:

```
@reboot /dir/xxx
/1 * * * * /dir/xxx
```

I do have a newline after the second line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder how your crontab accepted this. What you mean by `/1` in fact should be `*/1`. Try it out.

And if it's all in one line, like:

```
@reboot /dir/xxx /1 * * * * /dir/xxx
```

Then there should be a new line between both (and `*/1`) instead of `/1`:

```
@reboot /dir/xxx
*/1 * * * * /dir/xxx
```

In the one line version `/1 * * * * /dir/xxx` would be treated and passed as arguments to `/dir/xxx`. With `*` undergoing path expansion.